# How to prove that $D_{\frac{1}{2}-\epsilon}^{uniform}(f)=n+O(log \epsilon)$?

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory, asymptotic-complexity

Where D is the best complexity by using a communication protocol to give an answer to the function f with a uniform distribution on inputs and with a probability of $1-\epsilon$ to give correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not a clue but

[image]

this is the expression in your question

Comment: Thanks, we solved it by chernoff bound. This problem is a bit complex.